# Why subpages not load after i migrate service to localhost

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost, smarty

Im still pretty newbie here, so here is my question.

I have to migrate my PHP website to localhost, dosent metter why.
I didnt have any idea why it dosent work i should only download it from FTP and run on xampp and it should work from start... So i did like that I get files from FTP to my PC then start to push it to XAMPP, after that i got some problems with database but ok i call to guy who have made this website and we solve it somehow but now still got some errors, the biggest issue is that i cant open any subpage on this website, only main page is loading all others are totally dead. and send 404 error. Already check google and stack for answear but I didnt get anything what could help me solve this problem.

If u guys got some pro tips how to make it I would send u much love :)

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

If u need some details guys I can check, now i know its smarty-cms website based on php 7.4? i guess or even 8 smth like that, I dont even know how to check it well i think on my host website isnt it? like I said im still pretty newbi.

@edit adding some screens + source code (don't know which file u would need) :/

Here is structure of project:

[image]

Here is log from XAMPP when I open apache access logs:

```
::1 - - [18/Aug/2021:12:16:20 +0200] "GET /kontakt HTTP/1.1" 404 296
```

And here is config file

,,,

```
   <?php
    ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", 3600);
    session_start();

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $conf = array();
    $conf['admin-email'] = "";
    $conf['admin-name'] = "";
    $conf['site_url'] = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $conf['site_url_static'] = '';
    $conf['site_url_orig'] = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    $offline_mode = 1;

   if ($offline_mode == 0) {
    $conf['db-user']="00370440_0000009";
    $conf['db-pass']="pCKa:ZgU:c,t";
    $conf['db']="00370440_0000009";   
    $conf['rootpath']="";
    } 
    else {
    $conf['db-user'] = "root";
    $conf['db-pass'] = "";
    $conf['db'] = "00370440_0000009";    
    $conf['rootpath'] = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\netcomplex-1';
    }

    $conf['mailer'] = "sendmail";

    $conf['path']['aktualnosci- 
    photos']=$conf['rootpath']."/static/zdjecia/ak/";
    $conf['path']['artykuly- 
    photos']=$conf['rootpath']."/static/zdjecia/a/";
    $conf['path']['slider- 
    photos']=$conf['rootpath']."/static/zdjecia/s/";
    $conf['path']['produkty- 
    photos']=$conf['rootpath']."/static/zdjecia/p/";
    $conf['path']['produkty- 
    zal']=$conf['rootpath']."/static/zdjecia/p/zal/";
    $conf['path']['produkty- 
    thumbs']=$conf['rootpath']."/static/zdjecia/pk/thumbs/";
    $conf['path']['producenci- 
    thumbs']=$conf['rootpath']."/static/zdjecia/pdc/thumbs/";
    $conf['path']['konsultanci- 
    thumbs']=$conf['rootpath']."/static/zdjecia/k/thumbs/";

    $conf['artykuly-link']=$conf['site_url_static']."/zdjecia/a/";
    $conf['aktualnosci-link']=$conf['site_url_static']."/zdjecia/ak/";
    $conf['slider-link']=$conf['site_url_static']."/zdjecia/s/";
    $conf['produkty-link']=$conf['site_url_static']."/zdjecia/p/";
    $conf['produkty-thumbs-link']=$conf['site_url_static']."/zdjecia/pk/thumbs/";
    $conf['producenci-thumbs-link']=$conf['site_url_static']."/zdjecia/pdc/thumbs/";
    $conf['konsultanci-thumbs-link']=$conf['site_url_static']."/zdjecia/k/thumbs/";

$conf['blog-lista-prefix'] = "/blog";
$conf['blog-post-prefix'] = "/post";

$conf['show_blog_root'] = false;
$conf['blog_tools_enabled'] = true;

$conf['tree_link_enabled'] = false;

$conf['login_page'] = "/tb-admin/login.php";

$conf['gmap-api'] = "AIzaSyBC1S5OtRBYAVwmt0AaKQR4OEFqrTcp37w";

$conf['other_listtype_array'] = array("103" => "lista blokowa");

foreach(array('_GET', '_POST', '_COOKIE') as $var){
    $$var = trim_deep($$var);
    $$var = stripslashes_deep($$var);
}

function stripslashes_deep($value){
    return is_array($value) ?
        array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
        stripslashes($value);
}

    function trim_deep($value){
    return is_array($value) ?
        array_map('trim_deep', $value) :
        trim($value);
}

?>
```

,,,

XOXO

Comment: We can't debug descriptions. Please provide a [mre] of the problem. Not necessarily code in this case, but config / file structure / sample URLs you're using etc.

Comment: yey i already add some source code and some screens from this project but in my opinion its totally mess, if u need some more information just ask :^)